# Transactions without outputs

Tags: blockchain

When crunching blockchain data, my script tripped up on transactions without any outputs (vouts). Is this Monero's equivalent of OP_RETURN script, or am I missing something?

After looking at some examples in a blockchain viewer, it appears that the value of the outputs goes to the miner, I will leave the question open for good suggestions as to what is going on there:

[Block 761388](https://xmrchain.net/tx/01b257e003e8686d3b153331480a558f19eb323379e7eb6484efb9c089b4b9e8) [Block 782656](https://xmrchain.net/tx/c83a2107e32b366704b9b747de2dfb1e008bf5cfcb0668f60132d5e2f8843848) [Block 844741](https://xmrchain.net/tx/2c81d050f135e387d5d5f72fac9da88960926dc8af5b5fd7be92a48c57b27d6a) [Whole block 1006680](https://xmrchain.net/block/38d58afd268cff6b7a42a3626184c1cf5417b26e9dca77004510a2b1c36ed5db)

Comment: Can you tell us the txhash or block height of such a transaction?

Comment: This is a recent example - https://xmrchain.net/tx/f6b1637c4d4c95db5f16a872dc678849346ca7324aef2711406fff25ad213108

Comment: Wow, I'm really surprised by that.

Comment: Note that, for all transactions, the sum of the inputs is equal to the fee. Thus, the output is going straight to the coinbase reward, which is a different transaction.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE What's odd is that after following the link to the transaction in block 761388, if the containing block is examined, the no-outputs transaction is not listed. Only a different miner reward transaction is listed. I assume this must be a bug in xmrchain?

Comment: Not entirely sure what is going on there, since [MoneroBlocks](http://moneroblocks.info/search/761388) also doesn't list the no-outputs transaction.

Comment: @knaccc I can assure you the transaction is on the blockchain. I'm pulling the data straight from monerod. One more problem is that there is a bug in xmrchain with blockchain indexing (it is off by one when using block id) - here is a link to the tx block on moneroblocks http://moneroblocks.info/search/761389

Answer (score 2):

Monero has no scripting language. Even though the Cryptonote paper describes a simple lightweight one, the code did not implement it at the time Monero forked.

Comment: You missed the point of the question - I'm not asking about Monero's scripting capabilities. If you are not familiar with BTC, OP_RETURN script means that the transaction is unspendable, provably so. Although this doesn't appear to happen here.

Comment: Transactions are neither spendable nor unspendable, that does not make sense. A transaction consumes inputs, and creates outputs. In Monero, it's the same. Inputs are consumed, and outputs (possibly none) are created.